# How to pretty print dict YAML-like in Python?

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary, yaml, pretty-print

I have a dict with strings, lists, numbers and so on simple types. I can pretty print it with `json.dumps`, but yaml would be cleaner. Can I print dict with yaml tools?

If I do

```
import yaml

with open("out.yaml", 'w') as out:
    yaml.dump(mydic, out)
```

I get a lot of boilerplate like `!!python/object/apply:collections.OrderedDict`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a representer that presents the `OrderedDict` as a normal YAML mapping:

```py
yaml.add_representer(OrderedDict,
    lambda dumper, data: dumper.represent_mapping('tag:yaml.org,2002:map', data.items()))
```

Or, if you are using Python 3.7+, just do away with `OrderedDict` and use `dict` since it retains insertion order from that version on. `dict` will presented without explicit tag by default.